# Trying to create a simple gradebook program

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is the code I have so far. It keeps looping to the beginning after i input the 5 numbers.

creating gradebook program that allows a user to specify the highest possible grade and then enter individual assignment grades. cannot have the input of grades over the specified highest value, or negative grades. also want to average the grades in the end

```
def gradebook():
    while True:
        print("what is the highest grade possible")
        inp = int(input())
        if inp == "":
            cap = inp
            gradebook = []
        for x in range(5):
            l = int(input("enter grade"))
            if l > cap:
                print("you cannot have a grade higher than " + str(cap))
                gradebook.append(l)
                print(gradebook)
```

Comment: Is this the entire program? What does _cannot have the input of grades_ mean? Have you done any debugging? I recommend the follow article: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A while loop is correct for this scenario, in this case nested while loops.

**Code**

```
def gradebook(number_of_assignments):
    # init
    assignment_grade_list = []
    assignment_count = 1

    while True:
        try:
            # highest grade
            highest_grade = int(input("What is the highest grade possible?:"))
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid input. The highest grade must be numeric.")
            continue
        else:
            while assignment_count in range(1,number_of_assignments+1):
                try:
                    # assignment grade
                    assignment_grade = int(input("Enter assignment #%s grade:" % str(assignment_count)))
                except ValueError:
                    print("Invalid input. The assignment grade must be numeric.")
                    continue
                if assignment_grade > highest_grade:
                    print("Invalid input. You cannot have a grade higher than %s." % str(highest_grade))
                    continue
                if assignment_grade < 0:
                    print("Invalid input. You cannot have a grade lower than zero.")
                    continue
                else:
                    assignment_grade_list.append(assignment_grade)
                    assignment_count+=1
            else:
                # average assignments
                return round(sum(assignment_grade_list)/len(assignment_grade_list),2)
                break

# gradebook
a = gradebook(5)
print('Average assignment score: %s' % a)
```